# Weird Python SyntaxError in if loop conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm getting a very strange Python 3 error when trying to compare three variables in a if loop.

```
if now.weekday() == 6 or minutesRemaining <= 60 or modeArg == "run":
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

What does this mean?

My code works when I compare modeArg by itself:

```
if modeArg == "run":
```

And also when I only write the first two statements:

```
if now.weekday() == 6 or minutesRemaining <= 60:
```

---

[My code is on GitHub.](https://gist.github.com/a0f989e693dd170620fd) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have something which looks like a space which isn't in that line:

```
\tif now.weekday() == 6 or minutesRemaining <= 60 or\xc2\xa0modeArg == "run":\n
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Incidentally, you probably want to avoid using tabs for indentation: four spaces make life much easier.

Comment: It's a non-breaking space, probably from copying and pasting from a web page.

Comment: Hmm, how did that get there? Thanks for the help! (I should turn on invisibles.)

Comment: @mr_schlomo: note that github highlighted it for you, if nothing else does.